# Display User Tag While Mapping discordjs mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, discord.js

So i am sorting a leaderboard and it is currently displaying the user's id. I want it to display the user tag then their balance.

I have this code

```js
    const lb = users
              .slice(0)
              .sort(({ Bobux: a }, { Bobux: b }) => b - a)
              .map(
                
                ({ User, Bobux }, pos) => `${pos + 1}. <@${ await client.users.fetch(User).tag}> - ${commaNumber(Bobux)} Bobux`,
              );
```

But I get the error

```
(node:13960) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: C:\Users\Sochum\Desktop\BobloxBot\commands\leaderboard.js:26
                ({ User, Bobux }, pos) => `${pos + 1}. <@${ await client.users.fetch(User).tag}> - ${commaNumber(Bobux)} Bobux`,
SyntaxError: Missing } in template expression
```

How would I display the user's tag while sorting and displaying the top 15 users? The variable for user id is `User`

If I don't do await, everything returns as undefined

Answer (score 1):

- You can use [`Discord.Collection()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection) to sort the data after fetching from mongoose database.

```js
const { Collection } = require("discord.js")
const collection = new Collection()

// collect every member's data in the guild
await Promise.all(
   message.guild.members.cache.map(async(member) => {
      const id = member.id
      const data = await <Schema>.findOne({ User: id }) // replace "<Schema>" with your Schema
      const currency = data.Bobux

   return collection.set(id, { id, currency })
   })
)

const lb = collection.sort((x, y) => y.currency - x.currency).first(15) // top 15 of the collected data

// destructing our data to send it in one message
message.channel.send(lb.map((v, i) => {
   return `\`${i + 1}\`. ${client.users.cache.get(v.id).tag}: ${v.currency}`
  }).join("\n")
)
```

Comment: I get the error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Bobux' of null
When using that code (I replaced everything properly)

Comment: try removing `await`, **`const data = <Schema>.findOne({ User: id })`**